# URL path gets converted to query string on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I am trying to get a button to load a new html page in a website I am building with jinja2. The button action in jquery is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<input id="str_A" class="form-control-custom" name="str_A" size="30" type="text" placeholder="1st String" />
<input id="str_B" class="form-control-custom" name="str_B" size="30" type="text" placeholder="2nd String" />

<button id="calcdynamic" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success">Calculate Edit Distance</button>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $("#calcdynamic").click(function(){
     var str_A = $("#str_A").val();
     var str_B = $("#str_B").val();
     var url1 = "dynamic/"+str_A+"/"+str_B;
     window.location. = url1;
  });
```

Now, here's the problem:

I need to pass data in the url path like `http://127.0.0.1:5000/dynamic/sgsdgdgsdgd/sdgsdg`, not as a query string as `http://127.0.0.1:5000/dynamic/?str_A=sgsdgdgsdgd&str_B=sdgsdg`. However when I try to reach the url through the jquery call method, I am sent to the query string link, which is a redirectment to the same page I am in at the moment, `http://127.0.0.1:5000/dynamic/`.
I use flask server (python) and it is configured to redirect like this:

```
@app.route('/dynamic/')
@app.route('/dynamic/<str_A>/<str_B>')
def dynamic(str_A=None, str_B=None):
```

At first, I thought this was a problem with flask server, but if I manually type in the URL `http://127.0.0.1:5000/dynamic/sgsdgdgsdgd/sdgsdg` it works fine.

Can anybody help please, it looks like a simple thing, but I haven't been able to figure out why it happens so far.

Comment: Try just adding a leading `/` since your page is already in dynamic directory path. `var url1 = "/dynamic/"+str_A+"/"+str_B;`. That will make it a root relative path

Comment: @charlietfl i tried this before and rechked again, but it doesnt changz anything. I don't understand how the query string gets generated!

Comment: No idea...it's clearly a back end issue though

Comment: just figured out the query string is generated from the `<form>` tage I inserted the html in. I removed the elements, and voila! I find it suprising that the form element generates a querystring even without any form action or button action. I hope someone explains...

Comment: Ahhh.....because default button type  is `submit`. Change `$("#calcdynamic").click(function(){` to `$("#calcdynamic").click(function(event){event.preventDefault();` to prevent form default submit process

Comment: perfect! makes sense now. Thank you!